# Return Total Rows from a table

Tags: php, mysql

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $output .= "<Reports>";

    $output .= "<ProjectName>";
    $output .= $row['ProjectName'];
    $output .= "</ProjectName>";

    $output .= "<ProjectCount>";
    $output .= $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)
    $output .= "</ProjectCount>";

    $output .= "</Reports>";
}
```

My SQL Query.

```
SELECT designation.desg_Name AS PM, project.ProjectName,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 1 THEN 'ScopeofWork' END AS ScopeofWork,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 2 THEN 'DesignDocument' END AS DesignDocument,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 3 THEN 'Storyboard' END AS Storyboard,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 4 THEN 'Alpha' END AS Alpha,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 5 THEN 'Beta' END AS Beta,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 6 THEN 'Gold' END AS Gold,
Case ProjectPhase.PhaseID WHEN 7 THEN 'TE Storyboard review' END AS 'TE Storyboard review'
FROM `tycodashboard` t JOIN project ON project.projectID = t.projectID
JOIN projectPhase ON projectPhase.PhaseID = t.PhaseID
JOIN designation ON designation.designationID = t.designationID
```

Can i return the number of rows in table like this, i am getting XML markup error.

Comment: What you want in project count? you must write query in where you get project count on other column (where get data from entire row but next query).

Comment: I am not able to use my Count in SP. that is what i was trying to get the total records through mysql_num_row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$output .= $row=mysql_fetch_array($result)` will output `Array` maybe you want `$output .= mysql_num_rows($result);`?

Comment: I think we need to see a bit more of your code, especially the SQL query that your using to feed $result

Comment: What does the xml output look like? Does it have a php error or warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function **count($array)** in php